# I see leshan server timeout to be 5 sec. How and where to increase leshan server timeout?

Tags: java, m2m, leshan

I am facing Leshan server read timeout while testing with GPRS device.

I see the present leshan timout to be 5 Sec which i prefer to increase.

CoAP retry in my application is 4 times which takes around 16 sec, 5 sec would not be sufficient.

Presently i am using Leshan Server `0.1.11-M15-SNAPSHOT`.

Answer (score 1):

After doing further research, found the answer to my question.

The leshan timout is hardcoded.

`ClientServlet.java` inside `package org.eclipse.leshan.server.demo.servlet`

[image]

So, its required to recompile.